# Did the Eggenberger-Pólya (1923) paper derive the negative binomial distribution with real-valued parameter?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, history

The negative binomial distribution can be derived in many ways, but two famous ones are due to Greenwood & Yule (1920) and Eggenberger & Pólya (1923). Greenwood & Yule assumed unobserved heterogeneity between individuals, and basically derived it as a Gamma-mixed Poisson. Eggenberger & Pólya, by all accounts, used an urn system to model positive contagion - i.e. after an 'event', the probability of an event increases at future trials.

Using the main ($r$, $p$) parameterisation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), the pmf can be written
$$P(Y = k) = {k+r-1\choose k}(1-p)^r p^k$$
When $r$ is an integer, this is sometimes called the Pascal distribution, and it comes with a nice interpretation as the number of Bernoulli($p$) trials until there are $r$ failures.

But it can be extended to real $r$ using the Gamma function:
$$P(Y = k) = \frac{\Gamma(k+r)}{k!\Gamma(r)} (1-p)^r p^k$$

When $r$ is real, this is apparently sometimes called the Pólya distribution... my question is why? Was this derived in the Eggenberger-Pólya (1923) paper?

Everything I've read seems to *hint* that it was, except for Johnson, Kotz & Kemp's (1993) *Univariate Discrete Distributions*, which only says it arises as a limiting form of the Eggenberger-Pólya urn model. An urn model suggests to me that they used integer values only, but unfortunately the paper is in German and I can't tell if they continued beyond this point to derive the real-valued version -- and I can't recognise any of the formulas as clearly being the second one above (choice of parameterisation notwithstanding).

I probably can't post the paper itself publicly; these are the details:

Eggenberger, F. and G. Pólya (1923). *"Über die Statistik verketteter Vorgänge."* ZAMM - Journal of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics / Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Mechanik **3**(4): 279-289.

DOI: 10.1002/zamm.19230030407

If anyone can read German, or knows more about the history of the negative binomial, I'd love it if you could shed some light on this for me.

Cheers!